# Internal Server Error on local execution

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, cloud9-ide

I have a "hello world" NodeJs Lambda I created using the templates available within Cloud 9. I can execute the Lambda locally and it runs successfully. I can execute the Lambda remotely and it runs successfully. I can deploy the Lambda and run the API Gateway version of the Lambda (both from Postman & from within the Cloud 9 editor) and it completes without problems.

If I run the API Gateway version of the Lambda *locally* I receive an internal server error. Leaving the settings as-is (which are all generated by Cloud 9) and switching to Remote execution, it runs without issue.

#### Local API Gateway Execution

[image]

#### Remote API Gateway Execution

[image]

I've created two different projects in Cloud 9, one with leaving everything the default, and the second with changing the runtime from node6.10 to node8.10. Both projects have the same issue and won't execute the API Gateway locally. Since it's running locally there aren't any logs in CloudWatch for me to look at. I'm at a loss as to what the issue is and what I need to do in order to solve it.

Comment: maybe your api gateway couldnt call the lambda function. can you check the IAM role if it has proper permissions to call a lambada? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/integrating-api-with-aws-services-lambda.html#api-as-lambda-proxy-setup-iam-role-policies

Comment: The deployed API Gateway works fine. It's when I run it locally (vs remote) in Cloud 9. The EC2 I'm running Cloud 9 against (along with my IAM User) have AdministratorAccess as a Policy (temporary for testing).